# Extend templated class to have operator bool on object<bool> instances

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to extend a template to add a function for a specific type.

This is what I have now:

```
template<typename T> class Item {
public:
    T value;
}
```

And I want to make it so `Item<bool>` has a `operator bool()`, like this:

```
template<> class Item<bool> : public Item<bool>{
public:
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return this->value; // error
    }
}
```

However, I get an error saying `class 'Item<bool>' has no member 'value'`.

What am I missing?

Comment: IMO, you cannot make a class inherit from itself ... Please consider renaming your `Item` template to something like `BaseItem`, and then make your `Item` class inherit from `BaseItem<bool>`

Comment: That's not the way you specialize a template class: `template<> class Item<bool> : public Item<bool> ...`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so how should I do it?
@Unda So there's no way to have `Item<bool>` have an extra function that `Item<anything but bool>` don't have?

Comment: Why not an an operator T for all types?

Comment: @NeilKirk because if I have e.g. `Item<std::string>`, what's `if (item_string)` supposed to mean?

Comment: @AcidShout This severely sounds like a XY problem for me. What do you want to achieve with this template class at all actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in my case, every item represents a value set by the user, and in case it's a yes/no (bool), I want to be able to use `if (should_do_x)` instead of `if (should_do_x.value)`. (`should_do_x` is `Item<bool>`)

Comment: @AcidShout I still don't get the requirement and use case. So what should the implementation actually do with a `Item<std::string> x;` instance, whenever `if(x)` is called?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's exactly what I want to avoid. I don't want anybody calling `operator bool()` on anything that's not `Item<bool>`, because how can you determine the boolean value of a string? It doesn't make sense, that's why I want it only on `bool`s.

Comment: I don't understand. You don't want `if (item_string)` to work, but you don't want to use `operator T` because `if (item_stirng)` won't work.

Comment: @AcidShout: Note that Neil is suggesting `operator T` for all types, NOT `operator bool`.  For `Item<bool>` this would allow both `if(item_bool)` and `bool t=item_bool` to work.  For `Item<string>` this would allow only `string t = item_string` to work.

Comment: @NeilKirk sorry if I didn't explain myself properly. I want `Item<bool> x; if (x)` to work, but anything else, including `Item<string> x; if (x)` to **not** work, as it's nonsense to try to evaluate strings as `bool`s.

Comment: Correct. Therefore it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @AcidShout _"that's exactly what I want to avoid ..."_ I've updated my answer `std::static_assert()` is your friend to detect wrong usage at compile time. And there are sensible semantics I can imagine for that `operator bool()` being applied to a `std::string` BTW (think of e.g.`!value.empty()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *extend* template class declarations by introducing arbitrary member function declarations on type specializations.

You need to have that operator declaration appearing in the original class declaration:

```
template<typename T> class Item {
public:
    T value;
    operator bool() const {
         std::static_assert
            ( !std::is_same<T,bool>
            , "bool conversion is not available for this template parameter type."
            );
    }    
}; // <<< Note the semicolon BTW
```

and specialize it:

```
template<> 
Item<bool>::operator bool() const {
    return value;
}
```

The [`std::static_assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) will prevent any code from compiling, where you don't like an instantiation to make sense, besides of your own specializations.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. However, why can't I extend templated classes? As far as I know, templated stuff is evaluated at compile time, and for every type there's a new class generated with that specific type. Therefore, I should be able to tell the compiler to add one more function to a specific type. Isn't that right?

Comment: @AcidShout You can actually extend derived templated classes using techniques like the CRTP (by means of mixin template parameters). Here are some leads [**"Possibility to mix composite pattern and curiously recurring template pattern"**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867901/possibility-to-mix-composite-pattern-and-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/13868031#13868031), [**"Access “this” pointer of concrete class from interface"**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085834/access-this-pointer-of-concrete-class-from-interface/29086484#29086484).

Comment: Should it still be operator T in the first case?

Comment: @NeilKirk You're right, I've changed that mistakenly.

Answer (score 2):

The specialized class is not valid, it derives from itself. If you want to include some code in every specialization of a template class, you need to write this differently:

```
template<typename T> class ItemBase {
public:
    T value;
}

template<typename T> class Item {
    // generic implementation here
}

template<> class Item<bool> : public ItemBase<bool> {
public:
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return this->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though `operator bool() const;` is missing in the original class declaration :-(.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's just fine, I only want the `operator bool()` to appear on `Item<bool>` classes.

Comment: You can also write `operator T() const` if you always want a conversion to `T`.

Comment: @KrzysztofKosiński no, I just want the `bool` conversion. My `Item` classes are storing values, and I want to be able to do `if (bool_object)` instead of `if (bool_object.value)`.

Comment: @AcidShout: Do you want `string t = string_object;` to compile?  Seems like it would be nice.  You do that by adding `operator const T&() const`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a class inherit from itself. You might be trying to simulate the openness of classes that you are used to from other languages, e.g,. Python. However, C++ classes are not open - you cannot add to their implementation after defining them. With template classes, this means explicitly specializing the definition for your particular case. Yes, this does require code repetition if you do not design your class hierarchy correctly.

```
template<> class Item<bool>
{
public:
    bool value;
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return this->value; // error
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'correctly'? How would I do this 'correctly'?

Comment: @AcidShout You should separate out functionality and move as much of the generic content to a templated base class, say `ItemGeneric<T>` and restrict the specialization-specific code to explicit specializations of `ItemSpecific<T>` which inherits from `ItemGeneric<T>`.

Comment: It is all generic content for every `Item` object, and I'm doing exactly that: I've separated everything into `Item`, but I want `Item<bool>`s to have `explicit operator bool()` (specialization). Am I missing / misunderstanding something or there's simply no way to do it?