# C++ OOP duplicated inheritance pattern

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following classes, class A with a method, and a container class B:

```
class A
{
    void foo();
};
class B
{
    A * m_a;
    void setA(A* a)
    {
        m_a = a;
    }
    void callFoo()
    {
        m_a->foo();
    }
};
```

So now I want to extend the functionality of A to BarA adding fooBar(), so I also have to create a BarB to call this new method.

```
class BarA : public A
{
    void fooBar();
};


class BarB : public B
{
    void callFooBar()
    {
        // I know for sure its a BarA, but its saved as an A pointer
        BarA * barA = dynamic_cast<BarA*>(m_a)
        barA->fooBar();
    }
};
```

Now we create the caller:

```
class LetsFooBar
{
    BarA barA;
    BarB barB;

    void foobar()
    {
        barB.setA(&barA);
        barB.callFooBar();
    }
}
```

Everything works OK but there is the dynamic_cast issue in the pattern, as well as needing to extend the B class when wanting to extend the A class.

I would like to find a more elegant way to solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: What is it that you are ultimately trying to do? What is your issue, other than ugliness?

Comment: Use interfaces and [mixin implementation patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other comments that the optimal solution is going to be tied to *what you really want to do*.  However, here's another possibility that uses static polymorphism instead of dynamic polymorphism (including some small syntax changes to get it to compile):

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
protected:
    T * m_a;

public:
    void setA(T* a)
    {
        m_a = a;
    }

    void callFoo()
    {
        m_a->foo();
    }
};

class BarA : public A
{
public:
    void fooBar();
};

class BarB : public B<BarA>
{
public:
    void callFooBar()
    {
        m_a->fooBar();
    }
};
```

Note that this is just a slightly different take on Andrea's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the template tip, I finally implemented a mixin @πάνταῥεῖ.
With the mixin pattern I can statically use polymorphism. As the typename of the internal object is set when creating the class, there is no need to dynamic cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the `dynamic_cast`, you could store a `BarA` directly in `BarB` this way:

```
class BarB : public B
{
    BarA * m_bara;

    void setBarA(BarA* a) {
        m_bara = a;
    }

    void callFooBar() {
        m_bara->fooBar();
    }

    void callFoo() {
        m_bara->foo();
    }
};
```

Or this way, if you don't want override `callFoo` again

```
class BarB : public B
{
    BarA * m_bara;

    void setBarA(BarA* a) {
        m_bara = a;
        setA(a);
    }

    void callFooBar() {
        m_bara->fooBar();
    }
};
```

However, for a more elegant solution you have to be more specific on what you want to obtain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although this is a correct option too, I've marked @equality-7-2521 answer as correct because it suits better. The small issue here is that one will have a duplicate pointer to BarA and A in BarB class. Even thought they point to the same object, they have to be updated together whenever something changes.