# c++ confusion about embedding a struct name in itself

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, struct

I am learning boost and here is a piece of code from :http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/example/visitor.cpp
I am really confused in the definition of `struct edge_printer`, it uses a inheritance of `base_visitor`, but the type name of `base_visitor` templates is specified as `edge_printer` itself. Can I ask what this is called in C++?

```
template <class Tag>
struct edge_printer : public base_visitor<edge_printer<Tag> > {
  typedef Tag event_filter;
  edge_printer(std::string edge_t) : m_edge_type(edge_t) { }
  template <class Edge, class Graph>
  void operator()(Edge e, Graph& G) {
    std::cout << m_edge_type << ": " << source(e, G) 
              << " --> " <<  target(e, G) << std::endl;
  }
  std::string m_edge_type;
};
template <class Tag>
edge_printer<Tag> print_edge(std::string type, Tag) { 
  return edge_printer<Tag>(type);
}
```

Comment: Read about the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

This is called mix-in. See [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and [this post on mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept).