# Alternatives to CRTP

Tags: c++, traits, virtual-functions, crtp

Suppose we have following class with `virtual method`:

```
struct icountable{
   virtual int count() = 0;

   bool empty(){
      return count() == 0;
   }
}

struct list : public icountable {
...
}
```

Now suppose this can be rewritten with `CRTP`. Should look more or less like:

```
template <typename T> 
struct icountable{
   bool empty(){
      return static_cast<T*>(this)->count() == 0;
   }
}

struct list : public icountable<list> {
...
}
```

Now suppose the class itself does not need to use empty() method. Then we can do something like this:

```
template <typename T> 
struct icountable : public T{
   bool empty(){
      return count() == 0;
   }
}

struct list_base{
...
}

typedef icountable<list_base> list;
```

My question is for third example. Is this what is called `traits`? Is there advantages / disadvantages if I use those?

Comment: No, this isn't traits.

Comment: well then what is it, so I can google for it...

Comment: It could be (and is) called "mixin", which is a term that existed in older OO languages and seems to apply here.  I do not know if there is a better name for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, this is the mix-in concept, and you can find informations about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept).

The traits are different and [here](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442) you can find a basic example.