# Polymorphism in mixin classes - virtual functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism, mixins, virtual-functions

I'm currently reading about mixin classes and I think I unerstand everything more or less. The only thing I don't understand is why I don't need virtual functions anymore. (See [here](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/C%20%20_Mixins_-_Reuse_through_inheritance_is_good) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept/18775236#18775236))

E.g. greatwolf writes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept/18775236#18775236) here that virtual functions are not needed. Here is the example: (I just copied the essential parts)

```
struct Number
{
  typedef int value_type;
  int n;
  void set(int v) { n = v; }
  int get() const { return n; }
};

template <typename BASE, typename T = typename BASE::value_type>
struct Undoable : public BASE
{
  typedef T value_type;
  T before;
  void set(T v) { before = BASE::get(); BASE::set(v); }
  void undo() { BASE::set(before); }
};

typedef Undoable<Number> UndoableNumber;

int main()
{
  UndoableNumber mynum;
  mynum.set(42); mynum.set(84);
  cout << mynum.get() << '\n';  // 84
  mynum.undo();
  cout << mynum.get() << '\n';  // 42
}
```

But what happens now if I do something like this:

```
void foo(Number *n)
{
  n->set(84);    //Which function is called here?
}

int main()
{
  UndoableNumber mynum;
  mynum.set(42);
  foo(&mynum);
  mynum.undo();
  cout << mynum.get() << '\n';  // 42 ???
}
```

What value does mynum have and why? Does the polymorphism work in `foo()`?!?

Comment: You have the answer in the comments of that answer.

Comment: The mixin is intended to add functionality to the derived class. It is not intended to be used as an interface (which would require virtual functions).

Answer (score 0):

> n->set(84);    //Which function is called here?

`Number::set` will be called here.

> Does the polymorphism work in foo()?!?

No, without `virtual`. If you try the code, you'll get an unspecified value because `before` doesn't be set at all.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/UGQU48402)

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code in VS 2013, and it gives an unspecified number.

You got no constructor in your struct, which means that the variable before is not initialized.

Comment: I think the reason is he has default initialized `UndoableNumber mynum;` could have been done like `UndoableNumber mynum{};` to zero initialize the member

Answer (score 0):

Your code example invokes **undefined behaviour**, because you try to read from the `int` variable `n` while it is not in a valid status. The question is not what value will be printed. Your program is not required to print anything, or do anything that makes sense, although you are likely using a machine on which the undefined behaviour will only present itself as a seeminly random value in `n` or on which it will mostly appear as 0.

Your compiler likely gives you an important hint if you allow it to detect such problems, for example:

```
34:21: warning: 'mynum.Number::n' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

However, the undefined behaviour starts even before that. Here's how it happens, step by step:

> ```
> UndoableNumber mynum;
> ```

This also creates the `Number` sub-object with an **unintialised `n`**. That `n` is of type `int` and can thus have its individual bits set to a so-called [**trap representation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725809/trap-representation).

> ```
> mynum.set(42);
> ```

This calls the derived-class `set` function. Inside of `set`, an attempt is made to set  the `before` member variable to the uninitialised `n` value with the possible trap representation:

> ```
> void set(T v) { before = BASE::get(); BASE::set(v); }
> ```

But you cannot safely do that. The `before = BASE::get()` part is already wrong, because `Base::get()` copies the `int` with the possible trap representation. **This is already undefined behaviour.**

Which means that from this point on, C++ as a programming language no longer defines what will happen. Reasoning about the rest of your program is moot.

---

Still, let's *assume* for a moment that the copy would be fine. What else would happen afterwards?

`Base::set` is called, setting `n` to a valid value. `before` remains in its previous invalid status.

Now `foo` is called:

> ```
> void foo(Number *n)
> {
>   n->set(84);    //Which function is called here?
> }
> ```

The **base**-class `set` is called because `n` is of type `Number*` and `set` is **non-virtual**.

`set` happily sets the `n` member variable to 84. The derived-class `before` **remains invalid**.

Now the `undo` function is called and does the following:

> ```
> BASE::set(before);
> ```

After this assignment, `n` is no longer 84 but is set to the invalid `before` value.

And finally...

> ```
> cout << mynum.get() << '\n';
> ```

`get` returns the invalid value. You try to print it. This will yield unspecified results even on a machine which does not have trap representation for `int`s (you are very likely using such a machine).

---

Conclusion:

- C++ as a language does not define what your program does. It may print something, print nothing, crash or do whatever it feels like, all because you copy an unininitialised `int`.
- In practice, crashing or doing whatever it feels like is unlikely on a typical end-user machine, but it's still undefined what will be printed.
- If you want your derived-class `set` to be called when invoked on a `Number*`, then you must make `set` a `virtual` function in `Number`.