# Specialization with automatic inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, code-reuse, code-duplication

I am trying to reduce code duplication / verbosity as much as I can. What I am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
template<class A, class B>
  struct Base
    {
    void g() { std::cout << "generic derived";}
    };

  template<class T, class V>
  struct Derived : Base<T,V>
    {
    void f() { std::cout << "generic derived";}
    };

  template<class T>
  struct Derived<T, int> : Base<T,int>
    {
    // we inherit Base::g()
    void f() { std::cout << " derived for int";}
    };

  template<class T>
  struct Derived<T, double> // Here inheritance 
    {
    // we do not inherit Base::g()
    void f() { std::cout << " derived for double";}
    };
```

I'd like to reduce the verbosity of the code by avoiding in some way to repeat the : Base for each specialization. Are you aware of any template trick that I can use to solve this "problem" ? something that allows to automatically inherit the base functions or something that makes use of the using alias template keyword..

Thanks

[edit] inheritance for double, missed on purpose to show that for double there is no Base::g()

[edit2] just wondering if the following solution could work:

```
  template<class A>
  struct Base {};

  template<class A, class B>
  struct ToSpecialize{};

  template<class A, class B>
  struct ToUse : ToSpecialize<A, B>, Base<A> {};
```

so that I just need to specialize ToSpecialize and use ToUSe. I could also specialize Base if needed

Comment: Also you missed the inheritance for `Derived<double>`

Comment: post edited, thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Maybe base class as template parameter? Like they use commonly when implementing [mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept) in C++

Comment: @Steeve yes, I can work on that too, thanks