# GMOCK base class methods in derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock

I have a class that is inherited from another class as mentioned below:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Show(){}
};

class B : public A
public:
    void BMethod1(){Show()}
};
```

Now I am writing test cases for class B - so I have mocked class A :

```
class MockA : public A
{
    MOCK_METHOD0(Show, void());
};
```

Below is my Google Test framework test case:

```
TEST(BTEST , ShowMethod)
{
    B bobj;
    MockA aobj;
    EXPECT_CALL(aobj , Show());
    bobj.BMethod1(); // updated as from bobj.METHOD0()
}
```

But the test cases is calling the actual A::Show() implementation - how can call the Mocked version of MockA::Show() in such a case?

====================UPDATE=================================

Well the below implementation did the trick for me:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Show(){}
};

class B : public A
public:
    void BMethod1(){Show()}
};

class BMock : public B
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD0(Show, void());
};
```

Now use BMock object to test you class B required methods

Comment: Are you allowed to change `class B`?

Comment: I can if it fixes the issue and would also like to verify if some other mechanism exists

Answer (score 0):

First off:

```
    bobj.METHOD0();
```

is totally wrong. `METHOD0` is no valid symbol to access a mocked function.

What you want to test is that `B::BMethod1()` calls `A::Show()`, right?
So change that line to

```
    bobj.BMethod1();
```

---

You can change class `B` to take it's base class implementation as a template parameter:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Show(){}
 // ^^^^^^^ See note 1
};

template<class Base>
class B : public Base
public:
    void BMethod1(){Show()}
};
```

Then you use

```
B<A> bobj;
bobj.BMethod1();
```

in your production code, and

```
B<MockA> bobj;
EXPECT_CALL(bobj , Show());
bobj.BMethod1(); // <<< trigger the expectation
```

in your unit test code.

---

As a side node:

It's a well known pattern to inject base classes through template type parameters called [*Mixin*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept).
Though *Mixins* are mainly meant to provide piecewise implementations of interfaces, which are mainly meant to compose public interface implementations.

However, hitting such case when trying to unit test a class regarding those manners, would automatically lead me to the question, if I have a design flaw there:

> *Is `B` really an `A`, or is it rather meant to use an instance of `A` as an owned or referenced member variable?*

If I'm coming up with the need to test such in a unit test, I'd consider refactoring class `B` to something like

```
class B {
    A& a_;
public:
    B(A& a) a_(a) {}
    void BMethod1() { a_.Show(); }
};
```

And adapt the test scenarios accordingly:

```
TEST(BTEST , ShowMethod)
{
    MockA aobj;
    B bobj(aobj);
    EXPECT_CALL(aobj , Show());
    bobj.BMethod1();
}
```

---

As for your comment

> The intention is that the test case can return mocked values - EXPECT_CALL(mMockA, show()) .WillOnce(Return(false));

This should work with the example above:

```
EXPECT_CALL(bobj, Show()) .WillOnce(Return(false));
```

But requires that `Show()` is declared like

```
virtual bool Show();
```

in class `A` and like

```
MOCK_METHOD0(Show, bool());
```

in the `MockA` class.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>The `virtual` declaration is necessary in order to allow `MockA` to override the original implementation.</sub>

Comment: A's methods has virtual declaration. B class is created from A. Thanks but how now I can write in my test case that an Show call of MocakA is expected - like EXPECT_CALL(mMockA, show()) where B is created like B<MockA> -   where MockA is a class and mMockA is an object of type MockA. I mean how can we write EXPECT_CALL for MockA's method in my test cases. The intention is that the test case can return mocked values - EXPECT_CALL(mMockA, show()) .WillOnce(Return(false));

Comment: @Prakash I extended my example how to do the test a bit.

Comment: Thanks - but I know have a separate issue which occurs during compilation - which I believe is due to templating class A. In actual classA is defined in A.hpp and its implementation in A.cpp and same for B - B.hpp and B.cpp - now if I refer in B.cpp as like B<A> even though I have #include "A,hpp" in it I get undefined reference to A's constructor and methods during compilation - though I am not sure but my analysis leads to that currently - is that we need templated definitions and declarations in same file

Comment: @Prakash Sure making `B` a template, [requires to move all the implementation to appear in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). I seriously recommend to consider refactoring class `B` to use a reference to `A` provided at construction, instead of inheritance design.

Comment: @Prakash I have updated my answer again. It smells more and more that you have detected a design flaw, when trying to unit test your code.

Comment: I found an alternative to the solution as mentioned below - update the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Show() virtual to get MockA::Show() instead of A::Show().

Comment: I tried that but still the same issue - can you please provide the method implementation in details

Comment: Be carefull to put `public` keyword in MockA class too

Comment: something like this ?

`class A
{
public:
virtual void Show(){}
};

class MockA : public A
{
public:
MOCK_METHOD0(Show, void());
};`

Comment: @Nayfe Your answer doesn't really solves the OP's problem, but states a necessary fact to enable `MockA` to override that function.

Answer (score 0):

Well the below implementation did the trick for me:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Show(){}
};

class B : public A
public:
    void BMethod1(){Show()}
};

class BMock : public B
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD0(Show, void());
};
```

Now use BMock object for your test cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Isolator++](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Ipp) to create the test without the setup:

```
class A
{
public:
    void Show() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void BMethod1() { Show(); }
};

TEST(BTEST, ShowMethod)
{
    B bobj;
    auto aobj = FAKE<A>();

    bobj.BMethod1();

    ASSERT_WAS_CALLED(aobj->Show());
}
```