# Virtual inheritance impact on constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I've started learning about virtual inheritance (and how it may solve problems of having a class derived from two parent classes with same parent). To better understand the mechanism behind it, i made a following example:

```
class A {
public: 
    A(string text = "Constructor A") { cout << text << endl; }
};

class B:  public A {
public:
    B(): A("A called from B") { cout << "Constructor B" << endl; }
};

class C : virtual public A {
public:
    C() : A("A called from C") { cout << "Constructor C" << endl; }
};

class D :  public B,  public C {
public: 
    D() { cout << "Constructor D" << endl; }
};
```

I have `class A`, `class B` derived from `A`, `class C` virtually derived from `A`, and `class D` derived from `B` and `C`. In main i just form an object of `class D`: `D d;` and i get the following output

```
Constructor A
A called from B
Constructor B
Constructor C
Constructor D
```

What bothers me is, why is there **"Constructor A"** signalizing that it is not called by either `class B` or `C`. And why is there not **"A called from C"** before **"Constructor C"**. For the latter one i know it has to do with the `class C` being virtually derived so i guess it does not call `Constructor A` again since object from `class A` has already been formed (twice in fact).

**EDIT:**

In main i just make one object type D.

```
int main() {
  D d;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `main()` where you create instances of these classes?

Comment: @Hawky Sure, but like i said, i just make one object type D and that's it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line, my fault.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is add a set of pre-existing features to a base class as concisely as possible, then also look into [mix-ins with templated inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept) as an alternative to virtual inheritance. Put briefly, you can replace `struct FooableBase : virtual Base {...}` with `template <typename BaseT> struct Fooable : BaseT {...}`, and then replace `struct FooBar : FooableBase, BarableBase {...}` with `struct FooBar : Fooable<Barable<Base>> {...}`. I find the template approach to be **much** easier to work with.

Comment: @alterigel This looks like a very clean way to do it. I will definitely have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, since `B` derives from `A` non-virtually, `D` ends up with two `A` subobjects (as if you didn't use `virtual` inheritance at all).

The non-virtual `A` is constructed by `B()` (hence `"A called from B"`), and the virtual one prints `"Constructor A"` when constructed.

That's because the constructors of virtual (possibly indirect) bases are always called by the constructor of the most derived class (`D`), rather than by the constructors of any intermediate bases (`C`).

It means that `: A("A called from C")` in `C()` is ignored (since you're not constructing a standalone `C`). And since `D()` doesn't mention `A` in its member initializer list, the virtual `A` is constructed without any parameters (as if by `: A()`).

---

Also, it's worth mentioning that all virtual bases are [constructed before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Virtual_base_classes) the non-virtual ones.

So your code is guaranteed to print `Constructor A` before `A called from B`.

Comment: If i understood correctly, the initialization will begin from class C, which has been virtually derived from A, so a constructor with no parameters will be called from there. Then initialization will continue with X in a normal way (calling constructor A with parameter text and then with constructor X). Then initialization will move to Y and call its constructor, and then finally constructor of D will be called?

Comment: @dzi, what are `X` and `Y`?

Comment: @dzi No, initialization begins from the most derived class, `D`. It constructs all (possibly indirect) virtual bases (`A`), then all direct non-virtual bases (`B` (which in turn constructs the non-virtual `A`) and `C` (which doesn't construct any bases)).

Comment: So virtual base will be constructed first, even if it is not directly the base of most derived class?

Comment: @Evg sorry for confusion i meant B and C in places of X and Y.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  That is the answer i have been looking for all along. I thought it means that it prefers construction of virtual class but in each definition independently

Answer (score 3):

### The problem

Your code forgot something and you still have two `A` objects in a `D` object.  You can verify this claim by adding a public `int test` member to `A` and try the following code.  You will get two different addresses:

```
D d;
cout << &d.B::test <<endl;   // the non virtual A subobject of B
cout << &d.C::test <<endl;   // the virtual A subobject of C
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/jPXDTa)

### The solution

**All classes** that share `A` virtually and that directly inherit from `A` **must declare the virtual inheritance**.  So you need to correct class `B`:

```
class B:   virtual public A {...}  // you forgot the virtual here
```

The code snippets above would work as expected, and you could even address `d.test` without getting any ambiguity error.  [Online demo](https://ideone.com/bWSjYU)

### Edit:  The delicate construction of A

The C++ rules require each object with a virtual `A` sub-object to provide a constructor for `A`.  In your case, `D` should provide for the virual `A`'s construction.

Since there is no explicit constructor, `D` will look for a default-construct `A`. And it finds one, since you provide a default argument for the `A` constructor. It's misleading because it tells you "A constructor" when in reality it was `D` that used it.

If you remove this default argument, your code won't compile anymore.  You then need something like this to get `A` properly constructed:

```
class A {
public: 
    int test; 
    A(string text) { cout << "A is constructed: "<<text << endl; }
};

class D :  public B,  public C {
public: 
    D() : A("Mandatory, if there is no default consructor") { cout << "Constructor D" << endl; }
};
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/jqbFjd)

**Why are the C++ construction rules like that ?**  Because when you have virtual inheritance, there is no reason that the `A` construction by `B` is drawn over the construction by `C` . Nor the contrary. On the other side, both `B` and `C` define how to construct their `A` sub-object.  To solve the ambiguity in the choice of the right construction, this rule was decided. And it may  be painful if the virtual class doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: I was mostly aware of that. But what bugs me is "where is 'Constructor A' coming from", if it was called from class B or class C it would have said "A called from B/C", but it just says "Constructor A" like a constructor with no parameters was called.

Comment: @dzi Sorry, it's because of the default argument. See my edit

Comment: Another reason C++ rules are like that is because virtual inheritance has an extra level of indirection.  Following the rule of "you don't pay for what you don't use", C++  has an opt-in for "paying" for the extra overhead of virtual inheritance rather than it being the default.

Answer (score 2):

When a type has a virtual base, the virtual base gets constructed from the constructor of the most-derived type. So "Constructor A" is called from D's constructor.

A bit more detail:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {
    base() { std::cout << "base()\n"; }
    base(int) { std::cout << "base(int)\n"; }
};

struct i1 : virtual base {
    i1() : base(0) { std::cout << "i1()\n"; }
};

struct i2 : virtual base {
    i2() : base(1) { std::cout << "i2()\n"; }
};

struct d : i1, i2 {
};
```

Now, if the code creates an object of type `i1` the default constructor for `i1` calls `base(int)`, as written.

But when you create an object of type `d`, the constructor for `d` is responsible for constructing the `base` object. Since `d` does not have a default constructor, the compiler generates one that calls the default constructor for `base` before it calls the default constructors for `i1` and `i2`.

```
int main() {
    d d_obj;
    return 0;
}
```

the output here is

```
[temp]$ Clang++ test.cpp
[temp]$ ./a.out
base()
i1()
i2()
[temp]$
```

Note that the constructors for `i1` and `i2` **did not** construct the `base` subobject. The compiler took care fo that: the base should only be initialized once, and the constructor for `d` did that.

If you want a different initialization for the base object, write that in the constructor:

```
d::d() : base(2) {}
```

adding that to the class `d` produces this output:

```
[temp]$ Clang++ test.cpp
[temp]$ ./a.out
base(int)
i1()
i2()
[temp]$
```