# Compiler errors using inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

I'm a newbie in C++. I've written an example code that illustrates the problem and causes compiler errors.

```
class Quantifier;

class Node {
public:
    virtual void Match(/* args */) = 0;
};

class QuantifiableNode : public Node {
public:
    virtual void SetQuantifier(Quantifier *quantifier) = 0;
};

class NodeBase : public Node {
public:
    void Match() override {
        // Base behavior
    }
};

class QuantifiableNodeImpl : public NodeBase, // Needed to inherit base behavior
                             public QuantifiableNode // Needed to implement QuantifiableNode interface
{
public:
    void SetQuantifier(Quantifier *quantifier) override {}

    void Method() {
        this->Match();
    }
};

int main() {
    QuantifiableNodeImpl node;
    node.Match();
    return 0;
}
```

I get these errors:

```
main.cpp(27): error C2385: ambiguous access of 'Match'
main.cpp(27): note: could be the 'Match' in base 'NodeBase'
main.cpp(27): note: or could be the 'Match' in base 'Node'
main.cpp(32): error C2259: 'QuantifiableNodeImpl': cannot instantiate abstract class
main.cpp(20): note: see declaration of 'QuantifiableNodeImpl'
main.cpp(32): note: due to following members:
main.cpp(32): note: 'void Node::Match(void)': is abstract
main.cpp(5): note: see declaration of 'Node::Match'
main.cpp(33): error C2385: ambiguous access of 'Match'
main.cpp(33): note: could be the 'Match' in base 'NodeBase'
main.cpp(33): note: or could be the 'Match' in base 'Node'
```

As far as I understand, the compiler can't compile this code because class `QuantifiableNodeImpl` inherits class `NodeBase` and interface `QuantifiableNode` which both have a method `Match` (`NodeBase` implements it from `Node`, `QuantifiableNode` inherits abstract method from `Node`).
I need to have both of the interfaces `Node` and `QuantifiableNode` and use them in another code. Also, I need to have `NodeBase` class in order to separate base functionality (in my real code I have many derivatives of `NodeBase`).

Also, an object of class `QuantifiableNodeImpl` can't be created too, the compiler says that it has an unimplemented abstract `Match` method.

So, what should I do? Hope for your help!

Comment: You probably need to look up virtual inheritance. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're not entirely familiar with diamond inheritance. `QuantifiableNodeImpl` has two `Node` sub-objects, one via `NodeBase` and one via `QuantifiableNode`. The second `Node` subobject lacks a `QuantifiableNode::Match`.

It seems that this might not be intentional: is `QuantifiableNode` really supposed to be a `Node` in its own right? How is `QuantifiableNode::Match` supposed to work?

It might be that `Quantifiable` is more accurately modelled as a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773367/what-are-mixins-as-a-concept)