# How do i separate a class definition into 2 header files?

Tags: c++, class

I need to split one class (.h file)

```
#ifndef _L_H
#define _L_H
template<class L> class Myclass{
public:
  L();
  firstoperator(..);
  secondoperator(..);
private:
 ...
}
template <class L> Myclass<L>::L() ...
template <class L> Myclass<L>::firstoperator(..) ...
template <class L> Myclass<L>::secondoperator(..) ...
```

in two different .h file in the following form:

```
#ifndef _L_H
#define _L_H
template<class L> class Myclass{
public:
  L();
  firstoperator(..);
private:
 ...
}
template <class L> Myclass<L>::L() ...
template <class L> Myclass<L>::firstoperator(..) ...
```

---

```
#ifndef _L_H
#define _L_H
template<class L> class Myclass{
public:
  secondoperator(..);
}

template <class L> Myclass<L>::secondoperator(..) ...
```

how can I do it correctly without conflict?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can not split declaration on class into to header files. Although you can split definition into multiple files but thats not a good idea.

Comment: Do you have to declare all the methods as member functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use heritage to split class to two headers.

You can declare half class on the base and the other half on the derived.

like this:

```
class C12{
public:
  void f1();
  void f2();
};
```

can be splitted  to C1 and C12

```
class C1{
public:
  void f1();
};

class C12: public C1{
public:
  void f2();
};
```

now C12 is the same as before but splitted to 2 files.

Comment: This may have unwanted side effects. If so, mentioning/recommending [mixins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085265/what-is-c-mixin-style) would have been a better choice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That SO question you linked says mixins in C++ are through inheritance (unless I misread it), so I don't see how this answer is different from mentioning mixins?

Comment: @MicroVirus The [`template`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085265/what-is-c-mixin-style/7087257#7087257) actually makes a big difference!

Answer (score 16):

You can technically do it, but it's ugly. **Don't do it**.

Class1.hpp:

```
class MyClass
{
    int something;
    int somethingElse;
```

Class2.hpp:

```
    int somethingBig;
    int somethingSmall;
};
```

I hope it's clear how disgusting that is :)

Comment: +1 for the 'hacker' thinking. And +1 for probably breaking IntelliSense, and all other such things :P

Comment: IntelliSense suck with C++ projects that needs kind splitting anyway.

Comment: This feels like the worst practice of all time for any project size. But so smart! Tip of the hat, Sir

Answer (score 5):

> *"how can I do it correctly without conflict?"*

You can't. It's not possible in c++ to spread a class declaration over several header files (unlike as with c#). The declarations of all class members must appear within the class declaration body, at a single point seen in each translation unit that uses the class.

You can separate template specializations or implementation to separate header's though.