# Immutable member variables without creating a getter?

Tags: c++, idioms

Often I want to create member variables that are modifiable by the class, but unmodifiable by other outside classes. The way I do this is by making the member private, and then making a public getter function. This seems like extra work. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: You can make them `const`.

Comment: Making a member variable `const` will cause your default assignment operator to be deleted, so be careful with this. You'll need a custom `operator=` (or just not assign at all, which might be desirable)

Comment: I don't believe there is a simpler way in C++.  (Making them const would mean the class won't be able to modify them either)

Comment: @Eljay: That doesn't do what OP asked for.

Comment: If it helps, name your getter function for variable `x`, just `x()`, not `getx()`. It looks neater. It's certainly a style thing, but I don't like exposing any of my member variable as public ever. It's only functions for interface.

Comment: how about declaring the instance as const?

Comment: @einpoklum • The OP's description doesn't match the OP's title's question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a simpler way to this. Sorry... Remember that in C++ it's often the case that implementing a certain idiom takes some length and can get somewhat ugly, but in exchange you get more straightforward and elegant use.

What you *can* do is create a struct of all of these members of your class, and then at least not have to implement a separate getter for each of them - just use a getter for the struct which returns a `const&`.

Also (1): Follow @JohnFilieau's suggestion, so that the member is named, say `myclass::foo_` and the getter is named `myclass::foo()`, which doesn't make the implementation simpler, but makes the use more readable.

Also (2):  You could create a [mix-in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7085265/1593077) template for such a member (or several members, using a variadic template pack), and then inherit from it. Of course that might complicate your construction and perhaps other methods somewhat.

Comment: Great. I was actually creating and returning structs already, but I wasn't sure if this was a best practice.